# All daemons show in 'rofi -show run' using qtile

Tags: linux, arch-linux, rofi

I'm having a problem using rofi launcher with qtile Window Manager, the problem is that when I execute "rofi -show run" (with my keybind assignment) and I get a list of all the daemons availables on the system:

[image]

I had tried OpenBox too as a Window Manager, and this problem don't happend.
So there are any solution to this problem?

Comment: That looks like a list of all executables, not just daemons, which is perfectly normal for `rofi -show run`. What do you *want* it to show? If just applications with .desktop files use `drun` instead of `run`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had tried to change run by drun and it works like I expected, Im going to investigate the differences :) @frabjous